# Can you identify this Minifig? Transparent skeleton with red extremities

Tags: minifigure-identification

Can you identify this Minifig?

[image: transparent skeleton with red extremities]

Comment: If you look at the answer to your [other minifig question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/16516/what-is-this-minifig-female-brown-hi-viz-overalls), you'll notice this minifig in that same set. This is [gb020 "Mayhem"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=gb020) - IIRC, that's the ghost in the rock concert scene.

Comment: This seems good enough to be an answer, to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Same as in OP's [other minifig identification question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/16516/), the answer lies within set [75828-1 "Ecto 1&2"](https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/ecto-1-2-75828).

The minifig is [gb020 "Mayhem"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=gb020). If I remember the movie correctly, this is the ghost that interrupts the rock concert.