# What is this minifig? Female brown hi-viz overalls

Tags: minifigure-identification

[image]

Can you identify this Minifig?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's from set [75828-1 "Ecto 1&2"](https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/ecto-1-2-75828), part of the [Ghostbusters (2016) movie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1289401/) franchise.

[image: set image]

In particular, the minifig in question is [gb016 "Erin Gilbert"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=gb016#T=S.), depicting the [homonymous movie character](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1289401/characters/nm1325419)

Judging by the neck collar, your minifig seems to have some parts of the proton pack still attached, but not the entire assembly.

Comment: I'd also guess based on the color that the other minifig (whose feet we can see on the top-right of the image) is from the same set - there seem to be 3 other figures with that color feet, can't identify without seeing more of it.  (The grey top-left feet aren't enough to identify anything.)

Comment: I wonder if this Lego theme was as big of a flop as the movie it was based off of...